# Inserting end element of a vector at the beginning with iterator using vector insert in C++

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator

I have several vectors and I want to insert some of the values of the end of the vector into the beginning of it. For that, I have used the insert function of the vector. In every case, it worked except one - if the vector size is 3 and 1 value is inserted from the back, then the 2nd value is inserted in the front and not the last value.

This is what I tried (suppose vector is nums and number of values to be inserted is k):

```
nums.insert(nums.begin(),nums.end()-k,nums.end());
```

If nums = [1,2,3,4] and k=1, then the output:

```
nums = [4,1,2,3,4]
```

Which is correct, but if nums = [1,2,3] and k=1, then I got:

```
nums = [2,1,2,3]
```

Which is not correct. Even if I try k=2 for nums=[1,2,3] it provides the accurate answer.

Comment: The behaviour of `vector::insert` is undefined when used with iterators from the same vector, [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert). You should use some  intermediate storage, e.g. copy the elements you want to insert to a second vector, then insert from that second vector to the first.

Comment: You should `nums.reserve(nums.size() + k)` before the shown insertion.

Comment: Or, more appropriately, `nums.reserve(std::max(nums.capacity(), nums.size() + k));`

Comment: @273K Would that make a difference? It would be natural for an implementation of this form of `insert` to begin by reserving the necessary capacity in the vector.

Comment: @nielsen No, it's not natural, `first` and `last` can be invalidated after `insert` and in common case `last - first` sometimes doesn't work, for example if they are map or list iterators.

Comment: @273K It is still undefined behaviour and proabably going to fail, as the implementation of `insert` will likely shift the values in the vector before copying the new values and thus invalidate the iterators.

Comment: *I have several vectors and I want to insert some of the values of the end of the vector into the beginning of it* -- Maybe you should be using `std::deque` and `push_front()` in a loop instead of `std::vector`.  Insertion at the beginning of a deque is constant, while for every element you add to the beginning of the vector, the entire range of elements has to be moved down.